# Dictionary of life sciences or medical terminologies

Tags: dataset, data-mining, data, named-entity-recognition, tokenization

I'm exploring available open-source dictionaries with medical terminologies. I found [this](https://github.com/glutanimate/wordlist-medicalterms-en) but it's limited. Currently focusing on how to make use of [NIH](https://ncim.nci.nih.gov/ncimbrowser/). However, the challenge is that I'm running into blocks of text or group of words, this [lexicon](https://data.lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/lsg/lexicon/2021/release/LEX_DOC/LEXICON) for example. Parsing this could help but there're lot of common words. Is there a flat list of medical words available?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this questions here https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CarlosMougan thanks! Raised question there https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19862/dictionary-of-life-sciences-or-medical-terminologies